# Natural Math parser in opensource

Tags: math, matlab, open-source, latex, lyx

I want to start a new Open source project regarding natural math and Matlab, I am looking for an existing opensource math parser and display project that I can leverage.

Something with functionality like MathType Or Lyx that can render math expressions

I am looking to kick start my project from a code-base of such software

Any recommendations or suggestions may help me a great deal.

Thank you.

PS If you  think there is a better way to achieve this I would like to hear it also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbolic toolbox in MATLAB can output LaTeX code, which you can render by means of LaTeX itself or some alternatives such as MimeTeX.

```
s = sym('s');
latex(sqrt(s^3)); % will output '\sqrt{s^3}'
```

If you look around on the File Exchange, you can find lots of LaTeX-related MATLAB functions, e.g. [TeX Editor](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11946-tex-editor)

On the other hand, if that is not what you want: LyX also is open source, you could look for open-source Computer Algebra Software (CAS) such as Maxima. There is bound to be something that might do more or less what you want.